# Как сделать обработку чисел в Telebot?

Tags: python, telebot

Хочу написать бот-калькулятор на Telebot, нужно чтобы бот смог определять числа в сообщениях, пробовал через `string.isdigit()`, но выдавало ошибку синтаксиса. Работаю с библиотекой первый день, в целом с питоном неделю, вот код:

```
import telebot
import confige


bot = telebot.TeleBot(confige.config['token'])

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def start_message(message):
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Это бот калькулятор, чтобы начать вычисления введите первое число")

@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def first_num(message):
if message.text == ? : # Вот тут я не разобрался, как распознать число
 bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите второе число")

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: Заодно прочитайте про машину состояний, калькулятор такого вида без этого вы не сделаете

Answer (score 0):

```
if message.text.isdigit()
```

Вернет True если отправленный текст содержит только цифры

Answer (score 0):

Проверить отправлено ли вам именно сообщение, а не голосовое или т.д.
потом сделать проверку и тут писать операции дальше

```
if str(message.text).isdigit():
    ...
else:
    тут если сообщение не число написать об этом и заново функцию вызвать
```